# how do i set an image in button win32 sdk

Tags: winapi, bitmap, sdk, dialog, loadimage

How do I set an image to a button in a new dialog box(DialogBox2) which opens after clicking a button in a dialog box(DialogBox1)

case WM_INITDIALOG:

```
        hA1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDD_SCORPIO);
        hbitmap=LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_BITMAPAries),IMAGE_BITMAP,0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        if(hbitmap==NULL)
            MessageBox(hDlg,"load fail","Load",MB_OK);
        else
            MessageBox(hDlg,"load pass","Load",MB_OK);

        if(SendMessage(hA1,BM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)hbitmap))
            MessageBox(hDlg,"set pass","Set Image",MB_OK);
        else
            MessageBox(hDlg,"set fail","Set Image",MB_OK);
```

the bitmap loads but I am unable to set the image.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the way you doing it. Are you sure IDD_SCORPIO is the ID of your button? It does look like dialog window ID.

Comment: Yes, its the id of the button in new dialog window.

Comment: Have you set BS_BITMAP style for your button?

Comment: in the rc file i have,
PUSHBUTTON "SCORPIO", IDD_SCORPIO,90,160,60,40;

Comment: Thanks alot, after setting  BS_BITMAP, it worked well.
Thanks once again !!!

Comment: Hello, I set button style but i got empty return value from LoadImage Function. Example= PUSHBUTTON      "&Test",IDC_TEST,116,183,129,14, BS_BITMAP | WS_GROUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **BS_BITMAP** style for your button.